# App engine custom domain issue

Tags: dns, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have my app engine application setup for http://www.glam-fiesta.com and from app engine console I followed the steps mentioned to connect to godaddy and verify the ownership. After that google app engine was able to add the custom domain to the website hosted in app engine and everything is working fine. Recently I bought another custom domain www.glamfiesta.com from sedo auction and transferred to godaddy and followed the same process in app engine console to add this custom domain to the same application. The verification also worked fine and now I can see the two domains http://glamfiesta.com and http://www.glamfiesta.com got added in the app engine console. But everytime I try to open this URL it is not working and going to some other URLs. Please suggest where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sequence :

```
- goto google cloud dns ( google console -> Networking -> Cloud DNS)
  create a new zone for your app ... paste your domain previously
  created at your registrar ( GoDaddy ) ... here it will display 
  the spanking new dns nameservers (all four of them) keep them handy

- go into your domain registrar (GoDaddy) for your domain and 
  update your Custom DNS nameservers as displayed in above google cloud DNS

- Once you launch the app update the ephemeral External IP in
  Record Type A in google cloud DNS for the new zone from above
  which will make the deployed app visible from your domain URL
```